# How enable and disable values from 2 combobox. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have 2 comboboxes with same values,  my question is, if I selected item 1 from "combobox 1",  on "combobox 2", item 1 should be disabled or hide, and viceversa.

Is this possible?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzQ8L.png)

Comment: this actually not that difficult besides just having an Image can you show us or tell us what you have tried..? there are plenty of examples online on how to find the Index of a Selected Item in One Combobox vs Another.. please do a little more research and yes it's totally possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you populate your combobox but here is a sample for you,

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            items.Add("test");
            items.Add("asd");
            items.Add("qwe");
            comboBox1.DataSource = items;
            comboBox2.DataSource = items;
        }
```

On Combobox1's `selectedIndexChanged` event;

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> values = (List<string>)comboBox2.DataSource;
            values = items.Where(x => x != comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()).ToList();
            comboBox2.DataSource = values;
        }
```

Hope helps,